# Mac OS: Query SCNetworkInterface by BSD Name

Tags: macos

I see that I can get the BSD name for a network interface through SCNetworkInterfaceGetBSDName(). However, my program already knows the BSD name, so is there a way to get the SCNetworkInterfaceRef data for an interface based on its BSD name?

Answer (score 1):

It should work to get all interfaces using `SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll()` and then iterate over them until you find the one for which `SCNetworkInterfaceGetBSDName()` gives the target BSD name.